# Allow certain roles to log in only from specific page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I created a role "vendor", I also created two pages with a login form inserted with elementor, so I have now [www.mysite.com/login-vendor/](http://www.mysite.com/login-vendor/) and an other one [www.mysite.com/login-users/](http://www.mysite.com/login-users/), I would like that logging through /login-vendor/ is possible just for users with vendors role so I used this function but it works for every login page.. included /login-users/ , there's a solution?

```
function only_vendors($login, $user) {
 if($user->roles && !in_array('vendor',$user->roles)) {
    $logout_url = '/wp-login.php?mode=onlyvendors';
    wp_destroy_current_session();
    wp_logout();
    wp_redirect( $logout_url, 302 );
    exit();   
       }
    }
  add_action('wp_login', 'only_vendors',10,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is intentional, but you have a “!” In your validation which means that only users who are not vendors would have this logic applied to them. Try:

```
if($user->roles && in_array('vendor',$user->roles))
```

**Modified:** See the comments on this post — I did not understand the intention fully.

Comment: Is intentional, cause users that are not vendors will be kicked out, the problem is that i want apply this rule just for one login page and not for every login form on the site

Comment: Ah, okay. That makes sense. Sorry!

Comment: You may check $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] inside your function to know where the request come from.